# Parsing data from function in POSIX

Tags: bash, posix

I'm using POSIX. I have a function called `get_data` which returns:

```
4;Fix README;feature4;develop;URL5
2;Fix file3;feature2;develop;URL2
5;Fix README;feature2;develop;URL3
1;Fix file2;feature1;develop;URL1
```

I want to get to the URL (last part) of latest feature2 (based on the first index). In the above example, it will return `URL3` because it has feature2 in the third field and `5 > 2` in the first field.

The first thing I tried is:

```
url=$(get_data | grep feature2)
```

But I don't like this solution because the other lines also can contain feature2 on other fields. If it was Bash I would use `BASH_REMATCH` with regex, but here I'm not sure what is the best most elegant way to get that URL.

Is it possible to get some suggestion on how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Use `awk`:

```
url=$(get_data | awk -F";" '$3 == "feature2" && $1 > idx {idx=$1; url=$5} END {print url}')
```

After splitting each line into `;`-delimited fields, save the fifth field from a line whose third field is the desired feature, if the index is greater than the one you last saved. Once you have checked each line, output the final value of `url`.

Comment: Thank you. A bit rusty in AWK. I tried to run it but it says "^ syntax error" on the `{` after `index`.

Comment: Oops, I forgot `index` was a built-in function in `awk`, so you can't use that as a variable name. Also fixed the incorrect use of `$url` for `url` in the `END` block.

Comment: Thanks again. It still does not compile for some reason :(

Comment: I dropped a closing `'` when I pasted this from my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Using sort and awk, we can do

```
url=$(get_data | sort -t ";" -k 1nr,1nr file | awk -F";" '$3 == "feature2"{print $5;exit}')
```

Comment: Sorting is more expensive than simply walking through the file.

Comment: Indeed, but OP wants the LATEST one.

Comment: So? You've unnecessarily spent time ordering all the earlier ones, when that order doesn't matter. Sorting is O(n lg n), while find the maximum is only O(n).